# IBM Cloud: How to rename Code Engine project?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-code-engine

I created an IBM Cloud Code Engine project. The name was not well-chosen and needs to change. We already have a lot of resources in the project. I don't see an option to rename the project. Would I need to recreate the project and all its resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An IBM Cloud Code Engine project is the same as an IBM Cloud service instance. Thus, you can also manage it as a regular IBM Cloud resource. Use the CLI command [service-instance-update](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cli-ibmcloud_commands_resource#ibmcloud_resource_service_instance_update) to rename the project.

**Check for the projects:**

```
$ ibmcloud ce proj list
Getting projects...
OK

Name          ID                                    Status  Enabled  Selected  Tags  Region    Resource Group  Age  
toBeRenamed   0f36e9e0-2xyz-41bc-bxyz-2be32980e018  active  true     true            eu-de     default         10d
```

**Rename the Code Engine project as resource instance:**

```
ibmcloud resource service-instance-update toBeRenamed -n newCEproject
```

**Check the project again:**

```
$ ibmcloud ce proj list
Getting projects...
OK

Name          ID                                    Status  Enabled  Selected  Tags  Region    Resource Group  Age  
newCEproject  0f36e9e0-2xyz-41bc-bxyz-2be32980e018  active  true     true            eu-de     default         87s
```